# how to setup viewPager inside DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, drawerlayout

I am trying to put a viewPager in a row at the listView of DrawerLayout. Actully I want my side menu to contain only a viewPager! Here is my drawer adabter:

```
public class RightDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerBean> {

private Context mContext;
private List<DrawerBean> mItems;

public RightDrawerAdapter(Context context, List<DrawerBean> items) {
    super(context, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.layout.abc_list_menu_item_layout);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mItems = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position_item, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;

    if(position_item == 0) {
        final Drawable[] promotions = {
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.promotion),ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.promotion)
        };


        Holder holder = null;
        view = (View) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.right_drawer_header, null);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.viewPager_promotions = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_promotions);

        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(mContext,promotions);
        holder.viewPager_promotions.setAdapter(adapter);

        view.setTag(holder);
        view.setId(position_item+1);

    }else{
        view = convertView;
    }

    return view;
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size() + 1;
    }
}
class Holder {
    ViewPager viewPager_promotions;
}
```

But the result is that the DrawerLayout opens and it's all empty! there is nothing in it. And here is my ImageAdapter :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
private Drawable[] GalImages ;
public ImageAdapter(Context context , Drawable[] imgs){
    this.context=context;
    this.GalImages=imgs;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return GalImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    int padding = 0;
    imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    imageView.setImageDrawable(GalImages[position]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

Please any help ?

Comment: what exactly you want to do? where you want view pager? in drawer? i'm confused with your question

Comment: I want to set up the viewPager at the side menu listview as a row. @AjayPandya

Comment: Paste your ImageAdapter in question please

Comment: ok check it now @AjayPandya

Comment: Can you try with replace PagerAdapter  to PagerStateAdapter

Comment: can you give me example how to do that please ? @AjayPandya

Comment: Not sure but this may resolve problem replace your ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter with ImageAdapter extends PagerStateAdapter